# On a paper by Georg Pick

Tags: reference-request

Has any of you ever read the paper in which Georg Pick  made public [his famous formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem)? If so, would you be so kind as to tell me what it is that one can find in the introduction of it?

The complete bibliographical information of the paper in question is:

G. Pick, *Geometrisches zur Zahlenlehre*. Sitzungsberichte des deutschen naturwissenschaftlich-medicinischen Vereines für Böhmen „Lotos“ in Prag. 47. Band (1899), S. 315–323.

In case you wish to share with me an electronic copy of it, you can find my email account in my profile...

Let me thank you in advance for your attention and support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://biodiversitylibrary.org/page/14334051 $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $